# Extract stat_summary fun.y mean values in ggplot2 using facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, summary

I have searched the net and stackexchange for information on how to pipe the x and y values to a new varible when using `stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom="point")` values in `ggplot2` using `facet_grid` but have failed to find info regarding this.

How would this be achieved using e.g the cars dataset?

Would ggproto be usable for this?

**Update:**

```
> names(p2)
[1] "data"        "layers"      "scales"      "mapping"     "theme"      
[6] "coordinates" "facet"       "plot_env"    "labels"
```

Comment: could you please explain in more detail what your expected output is, preferably together with the code you have in mind for the plot so far?

Comment: Have you examined `names(plotname)` or `str(.)` for a result constructed with `ggplot`?